# cmd still closes after adding pause

Tags: batch-file

I wanted to write small batch file to search for text in multiple text files in a directory, and after it searches it immediately closes. So, I googled and most common answer I came across was adding `pause` some people also suggest using `set /p=` or `cmd` But none of them have worked. Am I placing `pause` in the wrong area of the file?

```
@echo off
findstr /m "softban soft ban" *.txt > results.txt
if %errorlevel% == 0(
echo Found a match, logged file in results.txt

)else(
echo no matches found

)
pause
```

updated code:

```
@echo off
findstr /m "softban soft ban" *.txt > results.txt
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 ( echo Found a match, logged file in results.txt )
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 ( echo no matches found )
echo press any key to exit...
pause >nul
```

Comment: You need spaces between the parentheses and else. `) else (`

Comment: Don't use the parentheses. Use only the if Equal == and if Not equal !=.... I.e. use 2 if statements instead of an if-else statements.

Comment: @JoeDF - Why? Also, this is batch; there is no `!=` operator.

Comment: Thanks for the help I updated the code.

Comment: @SomethingDark I know there is no `!=`. I just meant the logic. Also, I don't always trust the parentheses when it comes to batch files... :b

Comment: Also here a _space_ is missing before the `(`: `if %errorlevel% == 0 (`...

Answer (score 3):

You need spaces inbetween parantheses. try this code.

```
@echo off
findstr /m "softban soft ban" *.txt > results.txt
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
    echo Found a match, logged file in results.txt
) ELSE (
    echo not found
)
pause
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but I updated mine. I will still upvote though.